# Notifictaion not working in SSO enabled BOT build using teams tool kit

Tags: notifications, bots, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am new to teams tool kit . I am trying to build a  bot which can message and receive notifications. I am using the sample code available in teams tool kit. When i run the SSO enabled app alone, it works fine . When I run the notification bot alone it works fine and I get notification. When i try to merge both , the notification doesn't work . It fails to extract the member. The bot has to send notification to member not for channels. Currently i am testing in local in VS code only. Not using any Azure funtions.Using below end point to trigger notifiction http://localhost:3978/api/notification?email=test@abc.com

Below code fails and member is undefined

```
const member = await notificationApp.notification.findMember(
      async (m) => m.account.email === 'test@abc.com'

    );
    await member?.sendAdaptiveCard(AdaptiveCards.declare<CardData>(notificationTemplate).render({
      title: "New Event Occurred!",
      appName: "Contoso App Notification",
      description: `This is a sample http-triggered notification to`,
      notificationUrl: "https://aka.ms/teamsfx-notification-new",
    }));
```

Below is my index.js.

```
// Import required packages
import * as restify from "restify";
import * as path from "path";

// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
import {
  CloudAdapter,
  ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory,
  ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication, TurnContext
} from "botbuilder";

// This bot's main dialog.
import { TeamsBot } from "./teamsBot";
import config from "./config";
import { AdaptiveCards } from "@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools";
import notificationTemplate from "./adaptiveCards/notification-default.json";
import { notificationApp } from "./internal/initialize";
import { CardData } from "./cardModels";

// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
const credentialsFactory = new ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory({
  MicrosoftAppId: config.botId,
  MicrosoftAppPassword: config.botPassword,
  MicrosoftAppType: "MultiTenant",
});

const botFrameworkAuthentication = new ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication(
  {},
  credentialsFactory
);

const adapter = new CloudAdapter(botFrameworkAuthentication);

// Catch-all for errors.
const onTurnErrorHandler = async (context: TurnContext, error: Error) => {
  // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
  // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
  //       application insights.
  console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${error}`);

  // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
  await context.sendTraceActivity(
    "OnTurnError Trace",
    `${error}`,
    "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
    "TurnError"
  );

  // Send a message to the user
  await context.sendActivity(`The bot encountered unhandled error:\n ${error.message}`);
  await context.sendActivity("To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.");
};

// Set the onTurnError for the singleton CloudAdapter
adapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

// Create the bot that will handle incoming messages.
const bot = new TeamsBot();

// Create HTTP server.
const server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
  console.log(`\nBot Started, ${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});


// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  console.log('api/messages')
  await adapter
    .process(req, res, async (context) => {
      await bot.run(context);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // Error message including "412" means it is waiting for user's consent, which is a normal process of SSO, sholdn't throw this error.
      if (!err.message.includes("412")) {
        throw err;
      }
    });
});

server.get(
  "/auth-:name(start|end).html",
  restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  })
);

server.post(
  "/api/notification",
  restify.plugins.queryParser(),
  restify.plugins.bodyParser(), // Add more parsers if needed
  async (req, res) => {

    await target.adapter.continueConversationAsync(
      botId,
      target.conversationReference,
      async (context) => {
          // trigger sso
  });
    // By default this function will iterate all the installation points and send an Adaptive Card
    // to every installation.
    const pageSize = 100;
    const email= req.query.email;
    console.log('notiictaion api call ')
    let continuationToken: string | undefined = undefined;
    const member = await notificationApp.notification.findMember(
      async (m) => m.account.email === email

    );
    await member?.sendAdaptiveCard(AdaptiveCards.declare<CardData>(notificationTemplate).render({
      title: "New Event Occurred!",
      appName: "Contoso App Notification",
      description: `This is a sample http-triggered notification to`,
      notificationUrl: "https://aka.ms/teamsfx-notification-new",
    }));


    res.json({});
  }
);
```

Below is the Notifictaionapp configured

```
import { BotBuilderCloudAdapter } from "@microsoft/teamsfx";
import ConversationBot = BotBuilderCloudAdapter.ConversationBot;
import config from "./../config";

// Create bot.

    export const notificationApp = new ConversationBot({
      // The bot id and password to create CloudAdapter.
      // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
      adapterConfig: {
        MicrosoftAppId: config.botId,
        MicrosoftAppPassword: config.botPassword,
        MicrosoftAppType: "MultiTenant",
      },
      // Enable notification
      notification: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    });
```

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Archana - How are you fetching the member details? Is this a predefined method to get the member notificationApp.notification.findMember ?

Comment: the code was predefined in the notification bot quick start template.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, seems the problem you met is `await notificationApp.notification.findMember(...)` returns undefined.

Please check whether your current project contains `.notification.localstore.json` file and the content in it is not empty. The code relies on the content inside it to search members. You can find more information at https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/Send-notification-to-Teams#customize-storage.

If the file is empty, you can uninstall the app in Teams and install it again so the package can record your installation to the file.

Comment: There is .notification.localstore.json file. When i created a new notifictaion app from the team tool kit template , it worked fine. After merging the sso code, im getting undefined member

Comment: Please verify your SSO configuration once again and check if it's working. Also, check if you are getting any error in Teams web client console in browser.